# /UnregServer does not unregister my service the first time. Why and how to fix?

Tags: c++, windows, service, windows-xp

I just renamed a service we use at work beside correcting things and recompiling.
This exe is put correctly as a Windows service
But when it comes to unregister it, it works only the second time.
I unregister it that way :
`myexe.exe /UnregServer`
The errorlevel is 0 the first **AND** second time, so no way for me to decrypt why it does not work the first time.
Does anyone encounter the same problem and how did you fix it?
Tell me if i missed informations.

Thanks.

Comment: Programmers use a debugger to find out why code misbehaves, it doesn't get more basic than that.

Comment: This is absolutely not a  debugger problem. This comes from the /UnregServer command which unregister a windows service. If it does not work without returning an error code, i don't know how to troubleshoot this problem. Next time try to read my case and be more helpful.